# How can I get the summary information from MS Word (.DOC) file?

Tags: php, c

I only need the **page count** property in PHP without using only thi built-in functions (not  framework and COM). The input is an "old" doc file.

Here is what I know, and I found about this topic, I hope it will help you to solve the problem:

SummarayInformation looks like this and it is in encrypted into the file code:
[image]:

I found some C files where the method of extracting that data can be found, but it is too difficult for me to understand that.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "wv_Base.h"
#include "wv_Common.h"
#include "wv.h"

#include "glib.h"
#include "ms-ole.h"
#include "ms-ole-summary.h"


/*
 * This is a simple example that take an ole file and prints some
 * information from the summaryinformation stream
 */


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
    {
    char *str = NULL;
    int ret = 0;
    short s = 0;
    long l = 0;

    MsOle *ole = NULL;
    MsOleSummary *summary = NULL;

    if (argc < 2)
        {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: wvSummary oledocument\n");
        return(1);
        }

    ms_ole_open(&ole, argv[1]);
    if (!ole)
        {
        fprintf(stderr,"sorry problem with getting ole streams from %s\n",argv[1]);
        return 1;
        }

    summary = ms_ole_summary_open(ole);
    if (!summary)
        {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open summary stream\n");
        return 1;
        }

    ms_ole_summary_get_string(summary, , &ret);

    if (ret)
      printf("PageCount is %d\n", l);
    else
      printf("no pagecount\n");


    ms_ole_summary_close(summary);
    ms_ole_destroy(&ole);

    return 0;
    }
```

about MS_OLE_SUMMARY_TITLE:

```
/**
 * ms-ole-summary.h: MS Office OLE support
 *
 * Author:
 *    Michael Meeks (michael@imaginator.com)
 * From work by:
 *    Caolan McNamara (Caolan.McNamara@ul.ie)
 * Built on work by:
 *    Somar Software's CPPSUM (http://www.somar.com)
 *
 * Copyright 1998-2000 Helix Code, Inc., Frank Chiulli, and others.
 **/

#ifndef MS_OLE_SUMMARY_H
#define MS_OLE_SUMMARY_H

#include <time.h>
#include <libole2/ms-ole.h>

/*
 * MS Ole Property Set IDs
 * The SummaryInformation stream contains the SummaryInformation property set.
 * The DocumentSummaryInformation stream contains both the
 * DocumentSummaryInformation and the UserDefined property sets as sections.
 */
typedef enum {
    MS_OLE_PS_SUMMARY_INFO,
    MS_OLE_PS_DOCUMENT_SUMMARY_INFO,
    MS_OLE_PS_USER_DEFINED_SUMMARY_INFO
} MsOlePropertySetID;

typedef struct {
    guint8          class_id[16];
    GArray *        sections;
    GArray *        items;
    GList *         write_items;
    gboolean        read_mode;
    MsOleStream *       s;
    MsOlePropertySetID  ps_id;
} MsOleSummary;

/* Could store the FID, but why bother ? */
typedef struct {
    guint32         offset;
    guint32         props;
    guint32         bytes;
    MsOlePropertySetID  ps_id;
} MsOleSummarySection;

MsOleSummary *ms_ole_summary_open       (MsOle *f);
MsOleSummary *ms_ole_docsummary_open        (MsOle *f);
MsOleSummary *ms_ole_summary_open_stream    (MsOleStream *stream,
                         const MsOlePropertySetID psid);
MsOleSummary *ms_ole_summary_create     (MsOle *f);
MsOleSummary *ms_ole_docsummary_create      (MsOle *f);
MsOleSummary *ms_ole_summary_create_stream  (MsOleStream *s,
                         const MsOlePropertySetID psid);
GArray       *ms_ole_summary_get_properties (MsOleSummary *si);
void          ms_ole_summary_close      (MsOleSummary *si);


/*
 * Can be used to interrogate a summary item as to its type
 */
typedef enum {
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_TYPE_STRING  = 0x10,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_TYPE_TIME    = 0x20,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_TYPE_LONG    = 0x30,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_TYPE_SHORT   = 0x40,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_TYPE_BOOLEAN = 0x50,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_TYPE_OTHER   = 0x60
} MsOleSummaryType;

#define MS_OLE_SUMMARY_TYPE(x) ((MsOleSummaryType)((x)>>8))

/* FIXME MS_OLE_SUMMARY_THUMBNAIL is Preview, no Security, isn't it? */
/*
 *  The MS byte specifies the type, the LS byte is the
 * 'standard' MS PID.
 */
typedef enum {
/* SummaryInformation Stream Properties */
/* String properties */
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_TITLE          = 0x1002,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_SUBJECT        = 0x1003,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_AUTHOR         = 0x1004,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_KEYWORDS       = 0x1005,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_COMMENTS       = 0x1006,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_TEMPLATE       = 0x1007,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_LASTAUTHOR     = 0x1008,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_REVNUMBER      = 0x1009,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_APPNAME        = 0x1012,

/* Time properties */
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_TOTAL_EDITTIME = 0x200A,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_LASTPRINTED    = 0x200B,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_CREATED        = 0x200C,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_LASTSAVED      = 0x200D,

/* Long integer properties */
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_PAGECOUNT      = 0x300E,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_WORDCOUNT      = 0x300F,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_CHARCOUNT      = 0x3010,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_SECURITY       = 0x3013,

/* Short integer properties */
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_CODEPAGE       = 0x4001,

/* Security */  
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_THUMBNAIL      = 0x6011,


/* DocumentSummaryInformation Properties */
/* String properties */
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_CATEGORY       = 0x1002,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_PRESFORMAT     = 0x1003,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_MANAGER        = 0x100E,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_COMPANY        = 0x100F,

/* Long integer properties */
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_BYTECOUNT      = 0x3004,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_LINECOUNT      = 0x3005,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_PARCOUNT       = 0x3006,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_SLIDECOUNT     = 0x3007,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_NOTECOUNT      = 0x3008,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_HIDDENCOUNT    = 0x3009,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_MMCLIPCOUNT    = 0X300A,

/* Boolean properties */
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_SCALE          = 0x500B,
    MS_OLE_SUMMARY_LINKSDIRTY     = 0x5010
} MsOleSummaryPID;


/* bit masks for security long integer */
#define MsOleSummaryAllSecurityFlagsEqNone        0x00
#define MsOleSummarySecurityPassworded            0x01
#define MsOleSummarySecurityRORecommended         0x02
#define MsOleSummarySecurityRO                    0x04
#define MsOleSummarySecurityLockedForAnnotations  0x08

typedef struct {
    GTimeVal time;
    GDate    date;
} MsOleSummaryTime;

typedef struct {
    guint32 len;
    guint8 *data;
} MsOleSummaryPreview;

gchar *         ms_ole_summary_get_string   (MsOleSummary *si,
                             MsOleSummaryPID id,
                             gboolean *available);
gboolean        ms_ole_summary_get_boolean  (MsOleSummary *si,
                             MsOleSummaryPID id,
                             gboolean *available);
guint16         ms_ole_summary_get_short    (MsOleSummary *si,
                             MsOleSummaryPID id,
                             gboolean *available);
guint32         ms_ole_summary_get_long     (MsOleSummary *si,
                             MsOleSummaryPID id,
                             gboolean *available);
GTimeVal        ms_ole_summary_get_time     (MsOleSummary *si,
                             MsOleSummaryPID id,
                             gboolean *available);
MsOleSummaryPreview ms_ole_summary_get_preview  (MsOleSummary *si,
                             MsOleSummaryPID id,
                             gboolean *available);
void            ms_ole_summary_preview_destroy  (MsOleSummaryPreview d);

/* FIXME The next comment isn't true, is it?
   Return TRUE if write is successful */
void            ms_ole_summary_set_string   (MsOleSummary *si,
                             MsOleSummaryPID id,
                             const gchar *str);
void            ms_ole_summary_set_boolean  (MsOleSummary *si,
                             MsOleSummaryPID id,
                             gboolean value);
void            ms_ole_summary_set_short    (MsOleSummary *si,
                             MsOleSummaryPID id,
                             guint16 i);
void            ms_ole_summary_set_long     (MsOleSummary *si,
                             MsOleSummaryPID id,
                             guint32 i);
void            ms_ole_summary_set_time     (MsOleSummary *si,
                             MsOleSummaryPID id,
                             GTimeVal time);
void            ms_ole_summary_set_preview  (MsOleSummary *si,
                             MsOleSummaryPID id,
                             const
                             MsOleSummaryPreview *
                             preview);

#endif  /* MS_OLE_SUMMARY_H */
```

msOle structure:

```
/**
 * Structure describing an OLE file
 **/
struct _MsOle {
    int               ref_count;
    gboolean          ole_mmap;
    guint8           *mem;
    guint32           length;
    MsOleSysWrappers *syswrap;

    char              mode;
    int               file_des;
    int               dirty;
    GArray           *bb;      /* Big  blocks status  */
    GArray           *sb;      /* Small block status  */
    GArray           *sbf;     /* The small block file */
    guint32           num_pps; /* Count of number of property sets */
    GList            *pps;     /* Property Storage -> struct _PPS, always 1 valid entry or NULL */
/* if memory mapped */
    GPtrArray        *bbattr;  /* Pointers to block structures */
/* end if memory mapped */
};
```

other resources:

http://slackware.mirrors.pair.com/slackware-8.1/source/gnome/libole2/libole2-0.2.4.tar.bz2
ftp://ftp.ca.com/caproducts/Opal/jasmine064/framework/include/

reference:
http://wvware.sourceforge.net/libole2/libole2.html

I have tired it this way - but I did not found the pagecount:

```
echo("<pre>");
$file = "files/doctest.doc";
if(!is_file($file))die("File not found.");

//bind file to a stream.
$handle = fopen($file, "rb");

//read file content
$content = fread($handle, filesize($file));

$binaryfile = "";
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($content); $i++) {
    //get ascii char
    $char = $content[$i];

    //get the acsii value 0-255 (2^8)
    $decimal = ord($char);

    //decimal number in base 200
    $binary =  base_convert($decimal, 10, 2);

    echo($char);

    echo sprintf(" %3d %08b",$decimal,$decimal);
    if($i % 4==0)echo("*");

    $bit32 = b($content[$i]).b($content[$i+1]).b($content[$i+2]).b($content[$i+3]);
    echo sprintf("<br><b>%d</b>",base_convert($bit32,2,10)); //32bit int


    echo("<br>");
}
fclose($handle);
```

thanks for any help!

Comment: First question: are you after the document summary information of the word document (e.g. author, date of last edit, pagecount, etc), or of the summary information for images embedded in your word document (as the screen image suggests) such as shutter speed, lens aperture, etc?

Comment: the displayed image shows a summaray data of an image because I did not found that for document... | I only need the pagecount (not the embedded images attr.)

Comment: why not run the c program to get it?

Comment: first: I dont have all the required files, second: page count information must immediately associated to the file after upload (so it must run on the server in php)

Answer (score 2):

A word document is a file in a very complex format.
The file is in a stream contained in a Windows Compound Binary File

- [Why does the file utility identify Microsoft Word files as CDF? What is this CDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914990/why-does-the-file-utility-identify-microsoft-word-files-as-cdf-what-is-this-cdf)
- http://www.bl.uk/aboutus/stratpolprog/ccare/introduction/digital/formats/windowscompoundbinaryfileformatspecification.pdf

The specifications requires knowledge of binary (little endian stuff) and FAT (because it uses a FAT in the format) and all kind of other stuff.

**Not using COM**

I presume you are not in Windows (or you would have used COM/OLE by now) so here is one program that can ready and manipulate Windows CDF files.  It is not a framework but a program you can call using `system("cdfprogram file.doc")` built-in php function.

- http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/common-data-format-cdf-files-818757/
- ftp://cdaweb.gsfc.nasa.gov/pub/cdf/dist/latest-release/linux/

**Another program made to ready word files**

- http://cdfread.sourceforge.net/

Same here, you install and you call using `system()` or any of its equivalent siblings.

**Why are the Microsoft Office file formats so complicated?**

Because of the following reasons:

1. They were designed to be fast on very old computers.
2. They were designed to use libraries.
3. They were not designed with interoperability in mind.
4. They have to reflect all the complexity of the applications.
5. They have to reflect the history of the applications.

Ref: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2008/02/19.html

**Conclusion**

There is no simple way of getting the number of pages from a word file using PHP built-in functions only.  You will have to read ALL the specifications from Microsoft and build a parser yourself.  This is a project on its own.  I do not think anybody will do that for you for free.

Why nobody tried?  Probably because nobody wants to invest that much time when there are libraries and framework that does the job already.  That is my opinion.

**Suggestion**

How about you create a web service that runs on windows machine (you will have access to COM library) and your main application can simply post the word file to your windows web service and your web service returns the number of pages to your main application.  Using COM, its so easy.

You can do this asynchroneous so that your upload is not slowed down and the upload can be in « pending validation » status while waiting for the web service to come back with an answer.

If you are using a web service, then it does not have to be on the same server as PHP itself.

The web service would do something like:

```
<?php

$word = new COM("word.application");
if (!$word) {
  echo ("Could not initialise MS Word object.\n"); 
  exit(1);
}
$word->Documents->Open(realpath("C:\\Test\\t.doc")); 

$pages = $word->ActiveDocument->BuiltInDocumentProperties(14); 
echo "Number of pages: " . $pages->value;

$word->ActiveDocument->Close(false); 
$word->Quit(); 
$word = null; 
unset($word);
```