# How to extract files from a bin archive using java?

Tags: java, zip, extract, bin

I have extracted a *.bin file from an Requirement Interchange Format-File(RIF) using `7Zip`, now I need to insert the "manual" operations into my tool of automation, which are:

1. Extract files
2. Read Directory Name
3. Rename the "[1]Ole10Native" -File

but I have problems in dealing with the bin file. I have tried with `TrueZip` but it didn't work, neither with the `ZipInputStream` from `java.util`.

> This is the archive structure in 7Zip :
>   http://development.dragosardo.de/BinReader/archiveStruckture.bmp
>
> This is the bin file:
>   http://development.dragosardo.de/BinReader/binary0.bin

How can I extract this file? Any idea?

Comment: 7Zip seems to support a large number of compression formats. It's possible that your .bin-file is not ZIP-compressed. You should attempt to figure out the exact compression algorithm before trying to implement the decompression.

Comment: The Linux 'file' command identifies your binary0.bin as a "CDF V2 Document," which [probably means it's a Microsoft Office document](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4914990/why-does-the-file-utility-identify-microsoft-word-files-as-cdf-what-is-this-cdf).  Running 'strings' on it seems to confirm this, as it shows, among other things, `<w:document … xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" …`

Comment: @VGR  : Yes, inside of this BIN is a Word Document. But my problem is that the sourceBIN isn't "clean". I can't reneame it "*.docx". I have now tried with Apache POI, but there i can only extract BINs with txt,xml,png and jpeg inside.with  docx,xlsx and PDF it don't work.